# Passing Variables to a Separate PHP page (Graphics Draw)

Tags: php, function

I have a graphics draw image in which I would like to pass in a variable to represent the height of my image (a rectangle). The variable is part of an array that grabs the number of units in a range from a column in my database.

I echoed the variable `$cred0` and it is displaying a number/value in my HTML page. I want to pass the variable/value to another page which draws my graphic in PHP. As of now, the image is showing up fine when I set the height with a number:

```
define('IMAGE_WIDTH', 50);    
define('IMAGE_HEIGHT', 200);
```

But when I replace the value of the height with the variable, the image does not output:

```
define('IMAGE_WIDTH', 50);     
define('IMAGE_HEIGHT', $cred0);
```

I am guessing the variable is not being passed into the the graphic draw .php page correctly. I have tried creating an include but that does not display the proper results. Any ideas on how I can pass this variable into another page and use it to replace the value of the height?

This is the PHP for the page with the graphic draw (bar_chart_image.php):

```
<?php

  define('IMAGE_WIDTH', 50);    // width of image
  define('IMAGE_HEIGHT', 200);   // height of image

// Create the image
  $img = imagecreatetruecolor(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);

  // Background colors
  $background_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 224, 224); // pink
  $font_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 117, 109, 109); // gray
  $line_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 42, 143, 193); // blue
  $pixel_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0); // black

// Fill the background
  imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, $background_color);

// Lines
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  imageline($img, 0, rand() % IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_WIDTH, rand() % IMAGE_HEIGHT, $line_color);
}

// Random dots

  for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    imagesetpixel($img, rand() % IMAGE_WIDTH, rand() % IMAGE_HEIGHT, $pixel_color);
  } 

 // Output the image as a PNG using a header
  header("Content-type: image/png");
  imagepng($img);
  imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

This is the page that contains the variable information and values (creditLimitTable.php):

```
<?php
require_once("./includes/database_connection.php");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // VARIABLES FOR CREDIT LIMIT RANGES

    $cred0 = '';
    $cred1_50000 = '';
    $cred50001_75000 = '';
    $cred75001_100000 ='';
    $cred_100000 = '';

    // QUERY TO GET DATA FROM CREDIT LIMIT COLUMN

    $credit_limit = 'SELECT creditLimit FROM customers ORDER BY customerNumber ASC';
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $credit_limit) 
        or die ('Error querying database');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="classic_cars.css" />
        <style>
            #table11 {
                height: 100px;
            }   
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p><img src="bar_chart_image.php" /></p>
        <?php
            require_once("./includes/navigation.php");
        ?>
            <h1>Credit Limit Table</h1>
            <div id="table11">
            <table border= "1"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Credit Limit</td>
                </tr>
            <?php

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $creditLimit = $row['creditLimit'];

                    // SHOW COLUMN WITH DATA 

                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>$creditLimit</td>
                        </tr>";

                    // ++ INCREMENT INTO ARRAY IF VALUE IN COLUMN IS WITHIN CERTAIN RANGE

                        if($creditLimit == 0) {
                            $cred0++;
                        }

                        if($creditLimit >= 1 && $creditLimit <= 50000) {
                            $cred1_50000++;
                        }

                        if($creditLimit>= 50001 && $creditLimit <= 75000) {
                            $cred50001_75000++;
                        }

                        if($creditLimit >= 75001 && $creditLimit <= 100000) {
                            $cred75001_100000++;
                        }

                        if($creditLimit > 100000) {
                            $cred_100000++;
                        }

                        // ARRAY

                        $credit_data = array(
                            array('0', $cred0),
                            array('1 to 50,000', $cred1_50000),
                            array('50,001 to 75,000', $cred50001_75000),
                            array('75,001 to 100,000', $cred75001_100000),
                            array('100,000', $cred_100000)  
                        );

                } // end while loop

            ?>

                <!-- DISPLAY HOW MANY TIMES A NUMBER IN SPECIFIED RANGE SHOWS UP -->

                <p><?php echo $cred0; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $cred1_50000; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $cred50001_75000; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $cred75001_100000; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $cred_100000; ?></p>

            </table>

        <?php
            require_once("./includes/footer.php");
            mysqli_close($dbc);
        ?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell how and where you are sending the variable value to your graph php code?

Comment: @anant kumar singh this is what I attempted, did not work:
define('IMAGE_HEIGHT', $cred0);

Comment: I am  talking about your two php codes that you shown? are they on same page, or on different page?

Comment: Are you trying to use define twice on different pages?

Comment: @anant kumar singh they are on two different pages (i added the page names in my code above if that helps others see that they are two different pages)

Comment: You have not to define twice your define command

Comment: @Ali Torabi - it is not defined twice. The second define is just updated with the variable I want to use in place of the height

Comment: @isha, you mentioned that when you echo the `$cred0` var, it displays correctly, have you tried converting it into an intager before using it? as far as I can tell, when the echo works, it isnt a matter of passing the variable to the current page. Try `define('IMAGE_HEIGHT', (int)$cred0);` to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: generate first the cred0 value and then call the image with a parameter of cred0:

Display page:

```
<?php
require_once("./includes/database_connection.php");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // VARIABLES FOR CREDIT LIMIT RANGES

    $cred0 = '';
    $cred1_50000 = '';
    $cred50001_75000 = '';
    $cred75001_100000 ='';
    $cred_100000 = '';

    // QUERY TO GET DATA FROM CREDIT LIMIT COLUMN

    $credit_limit = 'SELECT creditLimit FROM customers ORDER BY customerNumber ASC';
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $credit_limit) 
        or die ('Error querying database');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="classic_cars.css" />
        <style>
            #table11 {
                height: 100px;
            }   
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php
$data = "";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $creditLimit = $row['creditLimit'];

                    // SHOW COLUMN WITH DATA 

                    $data .="<tr>
                            <td>$creditLimit</td>
                        </tr>";

                    // ++ INCREMENT INTO ARRAY IF VALUE IN COLUMN IS WITHIN CERTAIN RANGE

                        if($creditLimit == 0) {
                            $cred0++;
                        }

                        if($creditLimit >= 1 && $creditLimit <= 50000) {
                            $cred1_50000++;
                        }

                        if($creditLimit>= 50001 && $creditLimit <= 75000) {
                            $cred50001_75000++;
                        }

                        if($creditLimit >= 75001 && $creditLimit <= 100000) {
                            $cred75001_100000++;
                        }

                        if($creditLimit > 100000) {
                            $cred_100000++;
                        }

                        // ARRAY

                        $credit_data = array(
                            array('0', $cred0),
                            array('1 to 50,000', $cred1_50000),
                            array('50,001 to 75,000', $cred50001_75000),
                            array('75,001 to 100,000', $cred75001_100000),
                            array('100,000', $cred_100000)  
                        );

                } // end while loop

            ?>

        <p><img src="bar_chart_image.php?cred0=<?php echo $cred0; ?>" /></p>
        <?php
            require_once("./includes/navigation.php");
        ?>
            <h1>Credit Limit Table</h1>
            <div id="table11">
            <table border= "1"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Credit Limit</td>
                </tr>

<?php echo  $data; ?>
                <!-- DISPLAY HOW MANY TIMES A NUMBER IN SPECIFIED RANGE SHOWS UP -->

                <p><?php echo $cred0; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $cred1_50000; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $cred50001_75000; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $cred75001_100000; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $cred_100000; ?></p>

            </table>

        <?php
            require_once("./includes/footer.php");
            mysqli_close($dbc);
        ?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Image generator page:

```
<?php

  define('IMAGE_WIDTH', 50);    // width of image
  define('IMAGE_HEIGHT', $_GET['cred0']);   // height of image

// Create the image
  $img = imagecreatetruecolor(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);

  // Background colors
  $background_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 224, 224); // pink
  $font_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 117, 109, 109); // gray
  $line_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 42, 143, 193); // blue
  $pixel_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0); // black

// Fill the background
  imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, $background_color);

// Lines
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  imageline($img, 0, rand() % IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_WIDTH, rand() % IMAGE_HEIGHT, $line_color);
}

// Random dots

  for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    imagesetpixel($img, rand() % IMAGE_WIDTH, rand() % IMAGE_HEIGHT, $pixel_color);
  } 

 // Output the image as a PNG using a header
  header("Content-type: image/png");
  imagepng($img);
  imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

Comment: You could understand what @kumar is looking for.

Comment: he need to send a parameter to the php image generator file, the value of that parameter must be generated before the echo of the img tag in other way the parameter will always be empty

Comment: I wasn't considering issue, I thought it's about including scripts not uri access. thanks

Comment: this works. I took out the `$data = ""`,  `<?php $data = ""`, and `$data .=` and it still works in updating the image height according to the variable

Comment: yes, but you need the $data part to generate the rows of the table

Answer (score 0):

Thats cause you might be passing the `$cred0` as a string, try `define('IMAGE_HEIGHT', (int)$cred0);`. Notice that we are casting the variable to an intager before using it.

Comment: good point - but I tried this in the graphics draw page and it made no difference